# ¿Por qué Spring me da error en autowired?

Tags: java, mvc, spring

He intentado varias soluciones sin resultados, no me ha pasado nunca antes esto con Spring, no me funciona nada. He probado cambiando las clases de paquetes, poniendo algunas etiquetas de scan pero nada me ha resultado, donde ponga `@Autowired` me pasa esto, y no puedo seguir avanzando, dejo una captura y código de las clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="Email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="Clave")
    private String clave;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getClave() {
        return clave;
    }

    public void setClave(String clave) {
        this.clave = clave;
    }

    public User() {
    }
}
```

Clase Ej

```
public class Ej {
    private String sr1;

    public String getSr1() {
        return sr1;
    }

    public void setSr1(String sr1) {
        this.sr1 = sr1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, deberías evitar usar imágenes para mostrar código, es imposible leer nada desde un móvil y no puedo copiar nada a una posible respuesta para indicar un error o dar una solución.

Comment: Además debes agregar el código de la clase Ej y PracticaApplication, ya que sin esas clases todas las respuestas serán subjetivas o basadas en posibles errores, razón por la que difícilmente recibirás una respuesta correcta. También te insto a leer el apartado de como preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @christian ¿La clase Ej está anotada con `@Bean`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, ...? ¿Tienes un fichero XML donde definas los beans de la aplicación (típico applicationContext.xml)?

Comment: La clase ej es un POJO, y la clase User es un entity

Comment: Si pongo `@Bean` a Ej me dice not applicable to type, en realidad nunca he puesto `@Bean` a ninguna clase anteriormente, es primera vez que me pasa este problema, he probado creando proyecto nuevo y da el mismo error

Comment: Perdona Christian, me he confundido por dos veces y te he puesto `@Bean` cuando quería decir `@Component`

Comment: Si, con `@Component` se soluciona, pero no recuerdo haber tenido que poner esa etiqueta anteriormente a las clases de los modelos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por aclarar un poco esto:

En general, cuando inyectas una dependencia con `@Autowired`, ese objeto es un bean de spring de la clase que sea (en tu caso Ej).

Con esto conseguimos que si inyectamos en varias clases diferentes la misma dependencia, todas compartirán el mismo objeto, no habrá un objeto diferente por clase.

Para declarar que una clase debe ser tratada como bean de spring, hay que anotarla con `@Component`, `@Service` o `@Repository`. En el fondo spring las trata de la misma forma, pero tienen diferente valor semántico para la lectura de tu código. Si esa clase va a trabajar para acceder a datos de una base de datos, de un fichero, etc, queda mejor si le pones `@Repository`. Si la clase funciona como un clase de negocio que recibe una entrada y la transforma, lo suyo es usar `@Service`. Para todo los demás, `@Component`.

Ahora bien, lo que me extraña es que quieras inyectar una dependencia de un POJO. Generalmente este tipo de clases sirve para guardar datos de negocio y lo normal es que en la aplicación se creen y se destruyen varias veces. No como los beans de spring, que suelen estar cargados en memoria desde el principio de la aplicación y no se suelen destruir.

Lógicamente no conozco la aplicación que estás tratando de hacer ni que uso le vas a dar a Ej, pero deberías replantearte si realmente quieres inyectar ese atributo con `@Autowired` o simplemente declararla como un atributo normal de una clase e inicializarlo con el operador `new`. Te deberías preguntar: ¿quiero que este objeto que estoy inyectando aquí lo compartan otras clases o quiero que este objeto solo tenga uso en esta clase? Si respondes afirmativamente a lo primero sigue con ese `@Autowired`, en caso contrario sería más lógico usar `new`.

Answer (score -1):

Es posible que el error se te esté dando por el hecho de que estás intentando hacer un `@Autowired` de una clase modelo. En todo caso deberías crear un `@Repository` para poder manejar esa clase (si es un modelo de BD).